# how to install webform template in visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using VS 2013 and I don't see a `webform` option when I try to add a new item. How do I install a `webform` template?

[image: WebForm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add a new Item within Console Application. It will not gonna allow you to do this. You can create a new web project and then try to add `webform` from there.